# Missing file when installing Twisted python?

Tags: python, twisted

I am installing Twisted 12.1, which must be done by downloading from Twisted website. I am getting the following error after `python setup.py install`, which complains that a script file in setuptools is missing. Script file seems should be installed along with Python2.6. Can anyone point me to the direction of where to find such script file?

```
Processing Twisted-12.1.0-py2.6-solaris-2.12-i86pc.egg
creating /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-12.1.0-py2.6-solaris-2.12-i86pc.egg
Extracting Twisted-12.1.0-py2.6-solaris-2.12-i86pc.egg to /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Adding Twisted 12.1.0 to easy-install.pth file
error: /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/setuptools/script template.py: No such file or directory
```

Comment: These seem related: [pypa/setuptools #33 - Rename 'script template.py' to 'script-template.py'](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/pull-requests/33/rename-script-templatepy-to-script/) and [#134 - Spaces in file names make it impossible to package for Solaris 9 and 10](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issues/134/spaces-in-file-names-make-it-impossible-to)

Comment: Thx for the link! When I did `ls -all /usr/lib/python2.6/vendor-packages/setuptools", the list does not contain a file starting with script. It seems to be a different problem?

Comment: 12.1 is installable via `pip`; why do you believe you need to get it from the Twisted website?

Comment: It looks like you are installing onto Solaris.  What version of Solaris? What architecture? What version of Python 2.6?  Are you using virtualenv?  Are you using a vendor-built version of Python, or did you build your own?

Comment: Please do not use Python 2.6.  Upgrade to at least version 2.7.  It is no longer security-supported (and has not been for 2 years now - https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.9/ ), and so by using it you potentially put your users at risk.

Comment: Please also do not use such old versions of Twisted; upgrade to *at least* 14.0.2, but please consider upgrading to the most recent version.  (Note that we have just stopped supporting Python 2.6 because it is no longer updated either.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error installing Ansible on a Solaris 11.3 machine. System Python was 2.7.9 but I think it's comparable, i. e. 'script template.py' didn't exist in /usr/lib/python2.7/vendor-packages/setuptools.

I was successful installing a separate copy of setuptools und using them afterwards.

I. e. download setuptools and install them in a custom location (example):

```
setuptools-20.10.1$ python setup.py install --prefix=/export/dist/Solaris-x86/stw/setuptools-20.10.1
```

Then build your other package with (in this example) `PYTHONPATH=/export/dist/Solaris-x86/stw/setuptools-20.10.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.